# auth0 is not returning roles information

Tags: asp.net, authentication, auth0

I am using auth0 for authentication. I want to fetch all users including their roles. I generated token in auth0 and when I try to execute it in Postman or fiddler tool, Sometimes it's giving roles and sometimes not. Same thing is happening in application also.

If I add manually in app metadata in role property as below, Then information is coming.

```
{
  "authorization": {
    "groups": [
      "Admins",
      "Users"
    ],
    "roles": [
      "Admin"
    ],
    "permissions": []
  }
}
```

But I fill, that if I change in authorization tab, It should effect here also.

Below is my code,

```
var apiUser = new ManagementApiClient("<<Token>>", new Uri("https://<<Domain>>/api/v2"));
 IPagedList<User> allUsers = await apiUser.Users.GetAllAsync();
```

Do I need to clear cache in auth0, If yes then how?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided it seems that you're using the [*Auth0 Authorization* extension](https://auth0.com/docs/extensions/authorization-extension) to configure user role information.

If this is the case you should notice that the extension logic is run at login time by the [means of a rule](https://auth0.com/docs/extensions/authorization-extension#rule-behavior-for-the-authorization-extension). When you have that extension installed you should also have a companion rule; in my account the rule is named *auth0-authz* and should be the same for your case assuming version 2.0 of the extension.

The impact of this is that the roles are surfaced at the user level at login time, so any changes to the configured roles will be seen next time the user logins.

> Note: Since this logic is part of a rule it will only be executed in the context of a login. If users are added to or removed from a group this will only be reflected within Auth0 after this user logs in again (eg: in the user's app_metadata or when calling the /userinfo endpoint).

You're querying the users directly through Auth0 Management API which may lead to the situation where the roles currently stored at the user profile are not up-to-date. If you are seeing stale information then this might be the cause.

---

On the other hand if your problem is not exactly this one, please provide further information and if possible steps to reproduce. For example, do the roles information show for one user but not the other or does it show for user A in one response, but then if you make another request the response does not include role information for that same user A?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. I've configured Auth0 Authorization extension well and so I can see `roles` in user's `/userInfo` Management API but can't locate roles attribute in token that I'm receiving after login. I've also set scope string to `scope: 'openid email roles'`.

Comment: For your reference, I'm using `RS256` algo to encrypt the token but I think it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I was not using the authorisation extension, but rather the standard role. So I've had to create the below rule.
More info here : http://isbyr.com/return-user-roles-in-auth0/

````
    function (user, context, callback) {
      // Get the user roles from the Authorization context
      const assignedRoles = (context.authorization || {}).roles;
      // Update the user object.
      user.rolez = assignedRoles;
      callback(null, user, context);```
````